# update manager notification never pop up

Tags: updates, update-manager

Hello I'm running Ubuntu 23.10.
Settings for update manager:
Control check -- Every day.
Requested action -- Immediately notify
... But even when updates are present (sudo apt update show them) notification doesn't appear in advance.
Could someone help me please ?